# JSONLD Issue: Works via IP but Fails with Domain/Sub-domain IN next JS 14

Tags: next.js, schema, json-ld, next.js14

Encountering a peculiar scenario with JSONLD: functions fine via IP address, but not through domain. Details: accessing via IP (e.g., http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/) works, but fails with domain (e.g., http://example.com/). Seeking insights on potential causes or overlooked configurations. Any troubleshooting advice?

```
 const jsonLd = {
   {
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "title": "Location Information",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "latitude": {
      "type": "number",
      "description": "Latitude coordinate of the location"
    },
    "longitude": {
      "type": "number",
      "description": "Longitude coordinate of the location"
    },
    "address": {
      "type": "string",
      "description": "Street address of the location"
    },
    "city": {
      "type": "string",
      "description": "City of the location"
    },
    "country": {
      "type": "string",
      "description": "Country of the location"
    },
    "postal_code": {
      "type": "string",
      "description": "Postal code of the location"
    }
  },
  "required": ["latitude", "longitude"]
}





<script
      type="application/ld+json"
      dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: JSON.stringify(jsonLd) }}
      key="product-jsonld"
    />
```

Comment: You're saying [JSON LD](https://json-ld.org/), but you've posted what is definitely a [JSON Schema](https://json-schema.org/).  These are two different things.

Comment: What is it that's working with IP addresses, but not domains?  I don't see anything that might even attempt to access external systems.  Also, what library are you using?  Can you post replication code?  I don't see anything wrong with the schema itself.

Comment: Thank you for your response! The issue on my webserver (nginx) has been successfully resolved. Now Schema is Working

Comment: It'd be great if you could provide an answer to your question to explain the resolution.  It might help someone in the future.